# Prototype AJAX call returns different results when the same request is triggered from two different events

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, prototypejs

I'm using Prototype / Javascript to implement a pager widget that moves between details views of search results on my PHP site.

To display the details view, the browser makes an AJAX call to a backend PHP page (on the same host) that returns the detailed information as JSON and renders it in the browser window.

I have two functions that trigger this behaviour: One bound to a **back** link, and one bound to a **forward** link. The problem I am having is that, although everything works fine when I trigger the behaviour from the **Forward** link, when I try it using the **Back** link the `transport.responseText` is empty, with status 0.

Here is the Javascript code that makes the AJAX call:

```
function displayCardDetails(cardid, index) {
    openOverlay('View Card', 800, 500);
    var url = 'php/card_service.php?action=getCardDetails&multiverseid='
            + cardid;
    var transport = null;
    new Ajax.Request(url, {
        method : 'Get',
        requestHeader : {
            accept : 'application/json'
        },
        onSuccess : function(transport) {
            if ($('transportFrame') != null) {
                $('transportFrame').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(transport);
            }
            var response = transport.responseText.evalJSON(false);
            if (response.status != 'Error') {
                var card = response.data;
                drawCardDetails(card);
                drawDetailsPager(card, index);
            } else {
                setOverlayContent('<p><strong>Error: </strong>'
                        + status.message + '</p>');
                setOverlayTitle('Error');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see from this, I have it temporarily writng the details of the request / response to a debug window in my UI.

The following are JSON-encoded views of the `transport` variable, both fo rthe same search result.

The first is when `displayCard(212578, 2)` is invoked from the **forward** link:

```
{
    "request" : {
        "options" : {
            "method" : "get",
            "asynchronous" : true,
            "contentType" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "encoding" : "UTF-8",
            "parameters" : "",
            "evalJSON" : true,
            "evalJS" : true,
            "requestHeader" : {
                "accept" : "application/json"
            }
        },
        "transport" : {
            "statusText" : "OK",
            "status" : 200,
            "response" : "{\"status\":\"OK\",\"message\":\"Retrieved Card\",\"data\":{\"multiverseid\":212578,\"name\":\"A Display of My Dark Power\",\"layout\":\"Common\",\"rarity\":\"scheme\",\"setCode\":\"ARC\",\"setName\":\"Archenemy\",\"cardsInSet\":195,\"block\":null,\"releaseDate\":\"2010-06-18\",\"castables\":[{\"castableid\":null,\"name\":\"A Display of My Dark Power\",\"type\":\"Scheme\",\"manacost\":null,\"text\":\"When you set this scheme in motion, until your next turn, whenever a player taps a land for mana, that player adds one mana to his or her mana pool of any type that land produced.\",\"power\":\"0\",\"toughness\":\"0\",\"loyalty\":0,\"life\":0,\"hand\":0,\"artist\":\"Jim Nelson\",\"number\":\"8\",\"flavor\":\"\\\"What would you say is my greatest attribute? Is it my gluttonous lust for power?\\\"\"}]}}",
            "responseType" : "",
            "responseXML" : null,
            "responseText" : "{\"status\":\"OK\",\"message\":\"Retrieved Card\",\"data\":{\"multiverseid\":212578,\"name\":\"A Display of My Dark Power\",\"layout\":\"Common\",\"rarity\":\"scheme\",\"setCode\":\"ARC\",\"setName\":\"Archenemy\",\"cardsInSet\":195,\"block\":null,\"releaseDate\":\"2010-06-18\",\"castables\":[{\"castableid\":null,\"name\":\"A Display of My Dark Power\",\"type\":\"Scheme\",\"manacost\":null,\"text\":\"When you set this scheme in motion, until your next turn, whenever a player taps a land for mana, that player adds one mana to his or her mana pool of any type that land produced.\",\"power\":\"0\",\"toughness\":\"0\",\"loyalty\":0,\"life\":0,\"hand\":0,\"artist\":\"Jim Nelson\",\"number\":\"8\",\"flavor\":\"\\\"What would you say is my greatest attribute? Is it my gluttonous lust for power?\\\"\"}]}}",
            "upload" : {
                "ontimeout" : null,
                "onprogress" : null,
                "onloadstart" : null,
                "onloadend" : null,
                "onload" : null,
                "onerror" : null,
                "onabort" : null
            },
            "withCredentials" : false,
            "readyState" : 4,
            "timeout" : 0,
            "ontimeout" : null,
            "onprogress" : null,
            "onloadstart" : null,
            "onloadend" : null,
            "onload" : null,
            "onerror" : null,
            "onabort" : null
        },
        "url" : "php/card_service.php?action=getCardDetails&multiverseid=212578",
        "method" : "get",
        "parameters" : {},
        "body" : null,
        "_complete" : true
    },
    "transport" : {
        "statusText" : "OK",
        "status" : 200,
        "response" : "{\"status\":\"OK\",\"message\":\"Retrieved Card\",\"data\":{\"multiverseid\":212578,\"name\":\"A Display of My Dark Power\",\"layout\":\"Common\",\"rarity\":\"scheme\",\"setCode\":\"ARC\",\"setName\":\"Archenemy\",\"cardsInSet\":195,\"block\":null,\"releaseDate\":\"2010-06-18\",\"castables\":[{\"castableid\":null,\"name\":\"A Display of My Dark Power\",\"type\":\"Scheme\",\"manacost\":null,\"text\":\"When you set this scheme in motion, until your next turn, whenever a player taps a land for mana, that player adds one mana to his or her mana pool of any type that land produced.\",\"power\":\"0\",\"toughness\":\"0\",\"loyalty\":0,\"life\":0,\"hand\":0,\"artist\":\"Jim Nelson\",\"number\":\"8\",\"flavor\":\"\\\"What would you say is my greatest attribute? Is it my gluttonous lust for power?\\\"\"}]}}",
        "responseType" : "",
        "responseXML" : null,
        "responseText" : "{\"status\":\"OK\",\"message\":\"Retrieved Card\",\"data\":{\"multiverseid\":212578,\"name\":\"A Display of My Dark Power\",\"layout\":\"Common\",\"rarity\":\"scheme\",\"setCode\":\"ARC\",\"setName\":\"Archenemy\",\"cardsInSet\":195,\"block\":null,\"releaseDate\":\"2010-06-18\",\"castables\":[{\"castableid\":null,\"name\":\"A Display of My Dark Power\",\"type\":\"Scheme\",\"manacost\":null,\"text\":\"When you set this scheme in motion, until your next turn, whenever a player taps a land for mana, that player adds one mana to his or her mana pool of any type that land produced.\",\"power\":\"0\",\"toughness\":\"0\",\"loyalty\":0,\"life\":0,\"hand\":0,\"artist\":\"Jim Nelson\",\"number\":\"8\",\"flavor\":\"\\\"What would you say is my greatest attribute? Is it my gluttonous lust for power?\\\"\"}]}}",
        "upload" : {
            "ontimeout" : null,
            "onprogress" : null,
            "onloadstart" : null,
            "onloadend" : null,
            "onload" : null,
            "onerror" : null,
            "onabort" : null
        },
        "withCredentials" : false,
        "readyState" : 4,
        "timeout" : 0,
        "ontimeout" : null,
        "onprogress" : null,
        "onloadstart" : null,
        "onloadend" : null,
        "onload" : null,
        "onerror" : null,
        "onabort" : null
    },
    "readyState" : 4,
    "status" : 200,
    "statusText" : "OK",
    "responseText" : "{\"status\":\"OK\",\"message\":\"Retrieved Card\",\"data\":{\"multiverseid\":212578,\"name\":\"A Display of My Dark Power\",\"layout\":\"Common\",\"rarity\":\"scheme\",\"setCode\":\"ARC\",\"setName\":\"Archenemy\",\"cardsInSet\":195,\"block\":null,\"releaseDate\":\"2010-06-18\",\"castables\":[{\"castableid\":null,\"name\":\"A Display of My Dark Power\",\"type\":\"Scheme\",\"manacost\":null,\"text\":\"When you set this scheme in motion, until your next turn, whenever a player taps a land for mana, that player adds one mana to his or her mana pool of any type that land produced.\",\"power\":\"0\",\"toughness\":\"0\",\"loyalty\":0,\"life\":0,\"hand\":0,\"artist\":\"Jim Nelson\",\"number\":\"8\",\"flavor\":\"\\\"What would you say is my greatest attribute? Is it my gluttonous lust for power?\\\"\"}]}}",
    "headerJSON" : null,
    "responseXML" : null,
    "responseJSON" : null
}
```

The second is when `displayCard(212578, 2)` is invoked from the **back** link:

```
{
    "request" : {
        "options" : {
            "method" : "get",
            "asynchronous" : true,
            "contentType" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "encoding" : "UTF-8",
            "parameters" : "",
            "evalJSON" : true,
            "evalJS" : true,
            "requestHeader" : {
                "accept" : "application/json"
            }
        },
        "transport" : {
            "statusText" : "",
            "status" : 0,
            "response" : "",
            "responseType" : "",
            "responseXML" : null,
            "responseText" : "",
            "upload" : {
                "ontimeout" : null,
                "onprogress" : null,
                "onloadstart" : null,
                "onloadend" : null,
                "onload" : null,
                "onerror" : null,
                "onabort" : null
            },
            "withCredentials" : false,
            "readyState" : 4,
            "timeout" : 0,
            "ontimeout" : null,
            "onprogress" : null,
            "onloadstart" : null,
            "onloadend" : null,
            "onload" : null,
            "onerror" : null,
            "onabort" : null
        },
        "url" : "php/card_service.php?action=getCardDetails&multiverseid=212578",
        "method" : "get",
        "parameters" : {},
        "body" : null,
        "_complete" : true
    },
    "transport" : {
        "statusText" : "",
        "status" : 0,
        "response" : "",
        "responseType" : "",
        "responseXML" : null,
        "responseText" : "",
        "upload" : {
            "ontimeout" : null,
            "onprogress" : null,
            "onloadstart" : null,
            "onloadend" : null,
            "onload" : null,
            "onerror" : null,
            "onabort" : null
        },
        "withCredentials" : false,
        "readyState" : 4,
        "timeout" : 0,
        "ontimeout" : null,
        "onprogress" : null,
        "onloadstart" : null,
        "onloadend" : null,
        "onload" : null,
        "onerror" : null,
        "onabort" : null
    },
    "readyState" : 4,
    "status" : 0,
    "statusText" : "",
    "responseText" : "",
    "headerJSON" : null,
    "responseXML" : null,
    "responseJSON" : null
}
```

I've run these two JSON dumps through a Diff, and the only difference between the two that it found was in the response text and status. As you can see from `request.url`, in both cases the URL used to call the backend PHP file is the same. When I copy the URL from the **back** request and call it manually from the browser, it returns the search result that I expect.

Bizarrely, it seems to make a difference which link is used to make the call. Switching the **back** behaviour to the **forward** link causes the **forward** link to page to the previous result.

The function that draws the pager, and the bound function for paging are:

```
function drawDetailsPager(card, index) {
    var foot = '';
    index = parseInt(index);
    var displayIndex = index
            + (searchResults ? searchResults.startResults + 1 : 1);
    if ((displayIndex - 1) > 0) {
        foot += '<a href="javacript:void(0)" id="cardDetailsPager_'
                + (index - 1) + '">Back</a>';
    }
    var totalResults = (searchResults ? searchResults.totalResults : 1);
    foot += '&nbsp;';
    foot += displayIndex + ' of ' + totalResults;
    foot += '&nbsp;';
    if (displayIndex < totalResults) {
        foot += '<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="cardDetailsPager_'
                + (index + 1) + '">Forward</a>';
    }
    setOverlayFoot(foot);
    // Set event handlers on forward / back arrows
    if ($('cardDetailsPager_' + (index + 1)) != null) {
        $('cardDetailsPager_' + (index + 1)).on('click', '', pageCardDisplay);
    }
    if ($('cardDetailsPager_' + (index - 1)) != null) {
        $('cardDetailsPager_' + (index - 1)).on('click', '', pageCardDisplay);
    }
}

function pageCardDisplay(event) {
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    var linkId = target.id;
    var indexExpr = /cardDetailsPager_([0-9]*)/m;
    var match = indexExpr.exec(linkId);
    if (match != null) {
        var index = match[1];
        var cardid = searchResults.cards[index].multiverseid;
        displayCardDetails(cardid, index);
    }
}
```

(Apologies for messiness - I plan to optomise it later)

So obviously this is confusing the heck out of me. Can anyone shed any light on this problem?

Thanks heaps for any help that anyone can give me :)

Addendum: This has been largely tested in Google Chrome, with PHP 5.4.16 running on a WAMP server on my Windows 8 laptop. My production server is running PHP 5.3.27 under Debian, and gives exactly the same results.

**Update:**

After some playing around, it seems the error only occurs when the `displayCardDetails(cardid, index)` function is invoked from the `pageCardDisplay(event)` event handler function.

The pager widget works as expected now, with the `drawDetailsPager(card, index)` function altered as follows:

```
function drawDetailsPager(card, index) {
    var foot = '';
    index = parseInt(index);
    var displayIndex = index
            + (searchResults ? searchResults.startResults + 1 : 1);
    if ((displayIndex - 1) > 0) {
        var backIndex = index - 1;
        var backId = searchResults.cards[backIndex].multiverseid;
        foot += '<a href="javascript:void(displayCardDetails(' 
            + backId + ',' 
            + backIndex + '))">&lt;</a>';
    }   
    var totalResults = (searchResults ? searchResults.totalResults : 1);
    foot += '&nbsp;';
    foot += displayIndex + ' of ' + totalResults;
    foot += '&nbsp;';
    if (displayIndex < totalResults) {
        var forwardIndex = index + 1;
        var forwardId = searchResults.cards[forwardIndex].multiverseid;
        foot += '<a href="javascript:void(displayCardDetails(' 
            + forwardId + ',' 
            + forwardIndex + '))">&gt;</a>';
    } 
    setOverlayFoot(foot);
}
```

This version of the function drops the event handlers, and puts the call to `displayCardDetails(card, index)` directly onto the **back** / **forward** links: e.g. `<a href=javascript:void(displayCardDetails(212578,2))">&lt;</a>`.

Obviously, this isn't the most elegant solution - I'd still welcome any insite into why calling the function from the event handler might cause problems.

Comment: That's very odd.  But, I'm not sure how we can help you.  There are too many moving parts here that we can't see.  Is there any way you can simplify the problem and still reproduce it?

Comment: After some playing around, it seems as if the problem only occurs when `displayCardDetails(cardId, index)` is called from the event handlers - if I invoke the function directly from the browser's console it works reliably every time.

As a temporary cludge, I've put the function call directly onto the links (writeup in main thread incoming). I wouldn't call that the most elegant solution, but at least it provides a pointer as to the source of the problem.